# Pass function as parameters vs setting a variable and passing it

Tags: c#, function, overhead

I bet this question has been asked before, but I can't really find out what i'm looking for, so excuse me in advance :)

is there a difference (programmatically speaking OR overhead speaking) between this:

```
 var data = GetProducts();
 GetAllData(data);
```

and this:

```
GetAllData(GetProducts());
```

what are the pros and cons of both methods if any? is there a more elegant/right way of achieving it (say Func<>)?

thanks in advance,
Rotem

Comment: Depends on Context - if you only use the result of `GetProducts` for this one function then both calls are equivalent and it comes down to preference (the temporary variable is nearly certainly going to be optimized out)

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. There may be dozens or even hundreds of reasons one may prefer the one over the other.

Comment: Can someone please explain why is my question down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it in two lines makes it easier to debug, because you can break on the second line and observe the value assigned on the first line.

The compiler will optimize them both into the same CIL anyway, so it's not a matter of efficiency.  It's all a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functional difference and when the code is translated into machine language (or JVM byte code or whatever), it will result in more or less the same low level code.

The main difference is a matter of (a) aesthetics and (b) maintainability of the code.  With respect to aesthetics, some may argue that the second form is prettier.  It's largely personal choice but I would argue that if the expression wasn't as simple as `GetProducts()` but was very long (e.g. `GetContext().GetProductService().GetProductsFor(GetContext().GetCurrentUser())` then breaking it up into two lines with an intermediate variable is more readable.

With respect to maintainability, I think you will find that having fewer variables is always better for future maintenance.  You are less likely to encounter bugs relating to side effects or changing assumptions.  In other languages you can use constructs like `const` or `final` to use the compiler to help protect against code rot, but I would still argue that it's cleaner to have fewer lines of code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: *" If you used `const` instead of `var`"* - you cannot replace `var` with `const` that simply doesn't compile. And `const` requires a compile time constant in C#

Comment: Yes, that comment wasn't intended to be specific to C# but a general comment on using compiler constructs provided by many languages out there.